# TideSDK : convert.exe returned non-zero exit status

Tags: tidesdk

I am running TideSDK on windows and facing a problem with ImageMagick this is the error that I see in the console

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['convert.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Aditya\\Desktop\\jitu\\Aditya\\dist\\win32\\Aditya\\Resources\\Starbucks-Logo-051711.gif', '-resize', '16x16^', '-gravity', 'center', '-background', 'transparent', '-extent', '16x16', 'c:\\users\\aditya\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpsr8kpf\\16.png']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

This is the entire output from the console: http://pastebin.com/ecr9Ktg3

I have tried running convert.exe with the exact same parameters from the command line, and it works perfectly fine. Also, what is surprising is that, the ImageMagick command does end up creating the 16.png file, but convert.exe fails with a 1 status code when I try to launch the app.

Comment: You should downgrade to 6.8.9-1. I think your problem is related to this issue: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=25667.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in ImageMagick 6.8.9-2. I just submitted a patch for this issue to our svn repository. You should downgrade for now, it will be fixed in 6.8.9-3. Next time you should report a problem with ImageMagick here: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=3.